# Enviando e-mail com anexo excel - Python

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, codificação-de-caracteres, smtp, mime-type

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

email_user = 'xxxx@gmail.com'
email_send = 'xxx@gmail.com'
subject = 'Python'

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = email_user
msg['To'] = email_send
msg['Subject'] = subject


body = "HI"
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

filename = 'caminho_para_arquivo\\Documentos.xlsx'
attachment = open(filename, 'rb')

part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')

attachment = base64.b64encode(bytes(attachment, 'utf-8'))

part.set_payload((attachment).read)

encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition',"attachament; filename="+filename)

msg.attach(part)
text = msg.as_string()
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(email_user, 'xxxxxx')


server.sendmail(email_user, email_send, text)
server.quit()
```

Estou recebendo o erro de:

```
TypeError: encoding without a string argument
```

Gostaria de saber se é possível enviar planilha ou qualquer outra extensão do excel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, é possível sim enviar qualquer outra extensão do Excel por email.

Olhando seu código fiz uma pequena mudança na parte de anexar o arquivo

```
part = MIMEBase('application', "octet-stream")
part.set_payload(attachment.read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="WorkBook3.xlsx"')
message.attach(part)
```